# Choosing one certain point (out of many) for nearby polygon based on coordinates and other similar attributes

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I am working on a project in which I have to find a certain lightning strike that caused an area to burn. For now, I have 1300 fire areas with approx. 27,000 lightning strikes in my QGIS project map. Both datasets have coordinates and fire/stroke dates.

For each fire area there 'should be' a lightning strike which sparked a fire (my task). However, as it is right now there are multiple lightning strikes within and nearby each fire area scattered over time (from 2007 to 2017). I have to be able to find the exact lightning strike based on the coordinates and from the dates of fire and lightning strikes.

Additional: I need it for every fire area (1300 areas) so yes automated as manual selection would take way too long. Further, I have included all lightning strikes of a fire area within a buffer of 1 km from the outer parts of the fire area. So in terms of coordinates, we are not talking about changes of more than .1 or .2 The temporal uncertainty can be bigger, as the lightning dataset varies largely within itself. Let's say 3 to 4 weeks of uncertainty. Oh, and output is less important, preferably a shapefile.

Is this possible with QGIS and, if so, how?

Comment: Please expand on your task: Is this to be done automated? For every fire? Or case-study like only for examples? What is the spatial and timewise uncertainty between lightning strike and outbreak of the fire? What is the intended output? Excel file, shapefile, map?

Comment: Hi @Erik
I need it for every fire area (1300 areas) so yes automated as manual selection would take way too long. Further, I have included all lightning strikes of a fire area within a buffer of 1 km from the outer parts of the fire area. So in terms of coordinates, we are not talking about changes of more than .1 or .2 The temporal uncertainty can be bigger, as the lightning dataset varies largely within itself. Let's say 3 to 4 weeks of uncertainty.
Oh, and output is less important, preferably a shape file.
Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide clarifications. It's not fair to those who would help to force them to mine the comment stream for critical information.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this spatial + temporal join using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Feel free to add any field of interest from the two layers.

In this example, `a` is the polygon layer (fire area), `pt` is the point layer (lightning strike). Both have a `dte` field containing the date (fire or lightning date). The query looks for spatial intersection, but you could also add a buffer here. The join condition also rely on the difference, in days, between the two dates. Since we consider before and after, the date difference can be negative so we use the absolute value (`abs()`)

```sql
SELECT  a.id as areaID, pt.*
FROM pt
  JOIN a 
    ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geometry, pt.geometry)  
     AND  abs(julianday(a.dte)-julianday(pt.dte)) <= 14
```

[image]

Comment: I have tested your solution now, however, it will not work as it is right now. I do not know where I do something wrong. I have tried to change the selection from FireArea.FireID as FireName, lightning.* to other things and it still will not work. I understand the method you are using, but it does not resolve my problem.